# Mask an area of an element to see and interact with area beneath

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to dynamically cut out an area of an HTML div and see and interact with the HTML beneath it?

For example, say I have a div of mixed HTML content of 500x500 centered on top of other HTML content. Now I want to punch a round hole through the top content so I can see and interact with the content beneath it. Is it possible?

I think they call it masking or knock out.

Comment: It's hard to understand how a question showing such little research effort could come from someone with your current experience on SO. [Here is](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) the very first result from Google on "html masks" What do you mean by "punch"? Do you mean `pointer-events` or visually? Or both? Have you tried any code and it didn't work?

Comment: It's called walking up in the middle of the night and posting a question. My bad.

Comment: Have A Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Same to you :) Thanks for link too. It was very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to interact with the portion beneath (through the cut-out area) then using `clip-path` would be the correct option in my opinion. Masks show the portion beneath but they accomplish it by making the cut-out area of the top element as transparent. So when there is any sort of interaction (even in the cut-out area) it is essentially happening on the top element only. When using `clip-path` the area that is cut-out is totally blank and the top element has nothing in there. So when that portion is hovered on, the interaction there is directly on the bottom element.

**Clip-path Demo:** (when the cut out area is hovered, the background of bottom element changes)

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.example div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom-layer {
  background: beige;
}
.bottom-layer:hover {
  background: chocolate;
}
.top-layer {
  background: tomato;
}
.top-layer:hover {
  background: hotpink;
}
#example1 .top-layer {
  clip-path: url(#circle);
}
#example2 .top-layer {
  clip-path: url(#pentagon);
}
```

```html
<div class='example' id='example1'>
  <div class='bottom-layer'>Some content</div>
  <div class='top-layer'>Top content</div>
</div>
<div class='example' id='example2'>
  <div class='bottom-layer'>Some content</div>
  <div class='top-layer'>Top content</div>
</div>

<!-- the clip-path definition -->

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='pentagon' clipPathUnits='objectBoundingBox'>
      <path d='M0.25,0.25 0.75,0.25 0.75,0.5 0.5,0.75 0.25,0.5 0.25,0 0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0.25,0z' />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='circle' clipPathUnits='objectBoundingBox'>
      <path d='M0.25,0.5 A0.25,0.25 0 1,1 0.75,0.5 L1,0.5 1,0 0,0 0,0.5 0.25,0.5 
               M0.75,0.5 A0.25,0.25 0 1,1 0.25,0.5 L0,0.5 0,1 1,1 1,0.5 0.75,0.5' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Sample Mask:** (hovering on the cut out area has no impact on the bottom element)

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.example div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom-layer {
  background: beige;
}
.bottom-layer:hover {
  background: chocolate;
}
.top-layer {
  background: tomato;
}
.top-layer:hover {
  background: hotpink;
}
#example1 .top-layer {
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 50%, transparent 50%, white 50%);
}
#example2 .top-layer {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top left, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='example' id='example1'>
  <div class='bottom-layer'>Some content</div>
  <div class='top-layer'>Top content</div>
</div>
<div class='example' id='example2'>
  <div class='bottom-layer'>Some content</div>
  <div class='top-layer'>Top content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelent answer, as always

Comment: Thanks a lot :) @vals

Comment: Thanks. FYI The clip path demo works and that's what I need, but I don't think the mask example is working. I'm using Firefox. I see two boxes one drawn further down the page than the other.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: Sorry, that was because I had used the property with `-webkit` prefix. Did not add the standard property because Firefox doesn't support pure CSS masks as yet. It supports the `mask-image` property only with a inline SVG mask definition.